# Resize iframe with Kibana

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, kibana-4

I'm trying to resize an iframe with a Kibana 4.1.1 dashboard within it. I've tried listening to the load event and get the contents, such as:

```
$("#dashboard-iframe").on('load',
    function()
    {
        console.log($("#dashboard-iframe").contents());
    }
);
```

It returns an empty object:
Object[]

I've even tried running on the console even after all the dashboard is loaded.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

a timeout, im searching also for an event that tells me about the dashboard reflow but in the meanwhile just put a timeout

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved this problem is by adding a listener on `'hashchange'` event on the `window`. And then filter the new url on `size_x` and `size_y`. The reason this works is because everytime a container is updated, the url is also updated containing the changes done to the dashboard.